# Complex Analysis Roots Problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some problem on finding roots and showing that they exist under certain conditions:

**Problem:** Prove that $e^z+z^3$ has no root in $\{z:|z|<3/4\}$ and has three roots in $\{z:|z|<2\}.$

I am preparing for my finals for complex analysis, and this is one of the review problems, but I cannot seem to solve it and its frustrating as I am stuck on this chapter complex roots and residues. I would appreciate if someone could show me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For the first part, consider the possible values of $|e^z|$ and $|z^3|$ in that disk. For the second part, use Rouche's Theorem.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure, I still am quite stuck at showing $3$ roots exist in $|z|<2$.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Are you familiar with Rouche's Theorem?

Comment: In my text I cannot find Rouche's theorem, so I tried to look it up and studying it now, but I am not sure how to apply this theorem to this problem.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis There are a bunch of examples on this site applying Rouche's Theorem to this type of problem; look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773276/using-rouches-theorem-to-find-number-of-roots?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162675/find-the-number-of-zeros-of-14z100-5ez-in-the-unit-disc-what-are-their-mu?rq=1 as examples. You want to express your function as a sum $f(z)+g(z)$, where you know how many zeroes $f$ has in $|z|<2$, and $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$ on the boundary $|z|=2$.

Comment: Hmmm Ok I will take a look at them and try to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: I just took a look at the problem again, but for when $|z|=3/4,$ can we go, let $g(z)=-z^3,$ then $|f(z)+g(z)|=|e^z|<1,$ but $|g(z)|=(3/4)^3,$ in which the Rouche's theorem fails to hold, hence cannot have a root in the disk |$z|<3/4?$

Comment: @AuroraBorealis If Rouche's Theorem fails to hold, we don't know how many roots there are.